# Web beacon trafficking with MimeKit

Tags: c#, asp.net, mimekit

Is there any possible way to create a web beacon/bug with mimekit? I have taken a look on how to embed images within the message body in MimeKit but I can't seem to figure out how to transform this into a web beacon/bug, does anybody know a way how to do this?

My code:

```
    private string makeMailContents(Klant klant, Mail mail)
    {
        var builder = new BodyBuilder();
        var path = Path.Combine("wwwroot/trackers/track_open.png");
        var img = builder.LinkedResources.Add(path);
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(mail.Content);
        string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        Type mt = mail.GetType();
        PropertyInfo mp;
        string code;
        string final = "";

        img.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();

        return string.Format(@"<img src=""cid:{0}"">", img.ContentId);// this does not load anything, I want this to be the url to the image
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, I just had to return the following:

```
return string.Format(@"<img src=""{0}"">", "http://localhost:5000/api/mail/track/open");
```

for some reason this only works with string.Format. You don't need MimeKit related functions to do this.

**NOTE**

The request only works once, at least in chrome, I believe that this is because of the cache